# How can I "compress" my tree into aggregate data on up the hierarchy in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, union

I have to get a list of limits for a the sub-parts of a level 1part.  Limits for some parts are null, and for those null parts, I have to query the level 2 parts that are on that part and give the MIN of the limits of those level 2 parts.  For some of the level 2 parts, I have to get the MIN of *their* sub-parts (the level 3 parts on that level 2 part) and roll that up to the level 2 aggregate.

**What would be your approach?**

In writing this, I realized that I could filter the nulled level 1 parts out and UNION it with a query that does the aggregation for nulled level 1 parts, but I want to make sure there's not a better solution.  I think I felt a little pigeon holed by the query that I was given originally, which gave the entire tree (lower level parts parts were joined to higher level parts using START WITH and CONNECT BY), and I was trying to compress it via clever SQL, but I could not.  Also, I'd like the query to work with n levels of aggregation, not a finite number based on how many times I want to copy-paste my UNIONs and subqueries.

This has to be done in SQL.  I can't use PL/SQL.

For simplicity's sake, think of the schema like this:

```
Assembly table
level1_serial | level2_serial
-----------------------------
1234          | null
123           | 1
123           | 2
123           | 3

Limit table
part_serial | limit 
-------------------
1234        | 1000
123         | null
1           | 500
2           | 400
3           | 600
```

In this case, I would need to return two records as follows

```
part_serial | limit
-------------------
1234        | 1000
123         | 400
```

Comment: Are all the levels stored in the same table?  It's easier to interpret if you provided an example or two.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    PART_SERIAL,
    MIN(LIMIT)
FROM (    
    SELECT 
        NVL(PRIOR LIMIT.PART_SERIAL, LIMIT.PART_SERIAL) PART_SERIAL,
        LIMIT.LIMIT LIMIT,
        LEVEL
    FROM 
        LIMIT
    CONNECT BY PRIOR 
        LIMIT IS NULL AND 
        PRIOR PART_SERIAL <> PART_SERIAL AND 
        INSTR(PRIOR PART_SERIAL, PART_SERIAL) > 0 AND LEVEL < 10
)
GROUP BY PART_SERIAL;
```

It's do the job, but it returns more results, so you must do filtering.